# SQL Developer : Try to connect to a remote DB (SSH)

Tags: ssh, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to set a connexion to a remote ORACLE db using SSH and SQL developer. 
The SSH connexion is working fine but when I try to set the db connexion and test, I have the following error :

```
 Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: Connection reset by peer, connect lapse 36 ms., Authentication lapse 0 ms.
```

Does anybody know how to fix it ?

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Show us your connection properties,.

Comment: It's saying we can get to the DB server from the tunnel endpoint

Comment: But what's the solution, the SSH host is connected ?

Comment: I'm seeing your error message again, Connection reset by peer. Something else is going on.